# Nonlinear elliptic equation with Dirichlet conditions without weak solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-analysis

I am not familiar with the theory of nonlinear PDEs and wonder if there is a theorem that states sufficient and necessary conditions for the existence of weak solutions to the problem

$\begin{cases}
-\Delta u= f(u)&\text{ in }\Omega\\
~~~u=0&\text{ in }\partial \Omega
\end{cases}$

Where $f$ is some convex and smooth real-valued function.
What particular example can you give?